# Optionally copy values between EMF attributes

Tags: jface, emf, eclipse-databinding

#### Question

Imagine following EMF-model based JFace-form

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| My text field1           :  __________________  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Inherit value from field1:  [x]                 |
| My text field2           :  __________________  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Corresponding EMF-EClass

```
class Model {
    String field1;
    boolean inherit;
    String field2;
}
```

Here the user should enter the value of the `field1`. Then he can

- check the checkbox to copy the value from `field1` to `field2`
- uncheck the checkbox and enter a different value for the `field2`

My question:

- *How this kind of pattern should be **properly** implemented using JFace data-binding?*

(The text field my be all kind of widgets including tables)

(I would like to leave the enabling/disabling `field2` text box out of the scope of this question)

#### Dirty solution

```
IObservableValue value1Obs = EMFProperties.value(field1).observe(model);
IObservableValue value2Obs = EMFProperties.value(field2).observe(model);
IObservableValue inheritObs = EMFProperties.value(inherit).observe(model);

IObservableValue copyObs = new ComputedValue() {
    @Override
    protected Object calculate() {
        if ((Boolean)inheritObs.getValue()) {
            return value1Obs.getValue();
        }
        return value2Obs.getValue();
    }
}
getBindingContext().bindValue(value2Obs, copyObs);
```

- **Don't use this**
- This works for simple attributes but don't work for lists/tables.
- Also in case `inherit=false` I bind `field2` to itself. This looks weird and may cause problems in the future.